# How to disable future dates with Dojo dijit.Calendar

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, dojo

Whats the most optimum method to disable future dates or render them "unclickable" with dijit.Calendar? I wanted to use constraints.max = new Date(), but I think that only works with dijit.form.DateTextBox.

Thanks,

Hank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken it should look something like this

```
require([
    "dijit/Calendar",
    "dojo/date",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Calendar, date){
    new Calendar({
        value: new Date(),
        isDisabledDate: function(d){
            var d = new Date(d); 
            d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            var today = new Date(); 
            today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            return date.difference(d, today, "day") > 0;
        }
    }, "mycal");
});
```